# S-Corp Take Home Estimation

Tags: united-states, taxes, s-corporation, payroll-taxes

Looking for an estimation of what the take home (i.e. after taxes) would be from an S-Corp.  Lets assume the following:

- The S-Corp has a single stock holder
- All other income is out of scope for this discussion.
- There are no deductible expenses
- Assume state tax is 5% (both wages and distribution)
- The S-Corp will be doing a 40/60 split between wages and distributions.

Let's work off of $100k for easier math.  I am just looking at this as a math exercise; I know there are other factors that will influence things like the 40/60 split, etc - these are out of scope.

I accept and understand all the disclaimers that will be include (IANAL, IANA Accountant, IANA Tax Guy ...)

Let me know if there are other data points that are needed to determine a ballpark estimate.

Thanks!